# Don't understand addEventListener behaviour

Tags: javascript

I have wrote this code in JavaScript :

```
window.onload = function() {
  var keyboard = new Keyboard();

  var gameCanvas = document.getElementById("gameCanvas").getContext("2d");
  var player = new Player(gameCanvas, keyboard);
  player.Init();

  setInterval(function() {
    gameCanvas.clearRect(0, 0, 1200, 300);
    player.Update();
  }, 20);
}

class Player {
  constructor(canvas, keyboard) {
    this._canvas = canvas;
    this._keyboard = keyboard;
    this._x = 100;
    this._y = 75;
    this._dx = 1;
    this.dy = 1;
  }

  Init() {
    this.Draw();
  }


  Update() {
    if (this._keyboard.GetIsArrowLeftDown())
      this._x -= this._dx;
    if (this._keyboard.GetIsArrowRightDown())
      this._x += this._dx;
    if (this._keyboard.GetIsArrowUpDown())
      this._y -= this._dy;
    if (this._keyboard.GetIsArrowDownDown())
      this._y += this._dy;

    this.Draw();
  }

  Draw() {
    this._canvas.beginPath();
    this._canvas.arc(this._x, this._y, 50, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    this._canvas.closePath();
    this._canvas.strokeStyle = "black";
    this._canvas.stroke();
    this._canvas.beginPath();
    this._canvas.arc(this._x, this._y, 50, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    this._canvas.closePath();
    this._canvas.fillStyle = "red";
    this._canvas.fill();
  }
}

class Keyboard {
  constructor() {
    this.isArrowLeftDown = false;
    this.isArrowRightDown = false;
    this.isArrowUpDown = false;
    this.isArrowDownDown = false;

    window.addEventListener("keyup", keyboard.OnKeyUpEvent);
    window.addEventListener("keydown", keyboard.OnKeyDownEvent);
  }

  OnKeyUpEvent(event) {
    if (event.defaultPrevented) {
      return;
    }

    var key = event.key || event.keyCode;

    if (key == "ArrowLeft")
      this.isArrowLeftDown = false;
    if (key == "ArrowRight")
      this.isArrowRightDown = false;
    if (key == "ArrowUp")
      this.isArrowUpDown = false;
    if (key == "ArrowDown")
      this.isArrowDownDown = false;
  }

  OnKeyDownEvent(event) {
    if (event.defaultPrevented) {
      return;
    }

    var key = event.key || event.keyCode;

    if (key == "ArrowLeft")
      this.isArrowLeftDown = true;
    if (key == "ArrowRight")
      this.isArrowRightDown = true;
    if (key == "ArrowUp")
      this.isArrowUpDown = true;
    if (key == "ArrowDown")
      this.isArrowDownDown = true;
  }

  GetIsArrowLeftDown() {
    return this.isArrowLeftDown;
  }

  GetIsArrowRightDown() {
    return this.isArrowRightDown;
  }

  GetIsArrowUpDown() {
    return this.isArrowUpDown;
  }

  GetIsArrowDownDown() {
    return this.isArrowDownDown;
  }
}
```

I have a `Keyboard` object which remembers which keys the user pressed.

`Player` is an object that draw himself.

I expected that when I press left, the shape would move to the left of the screen. But it's not working as expected.

It seems my `keyboard` object hasn't the good property values when read by the `player` object.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some issues:

- In the `Player` constructor you assign 1 to the `dy` property, but it is later referenced as `_dy`, so you should add the underscore here.
- In the `Keyboard` constructor you use `keyboard`, but that is undefined; you intended `this`.
- In those same lines you pass a reference to the `OnKeyUpEvent` and `OnKeyDownEvent` methods. But when they are called, they do not pass the current value of `this`, so you should `bind(this)` to make that happen.

Here is the corrected code:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var keyboard = new Keyboard();

  var gameCanvas = document.getElementById("gameCanvas").getContext("2d");
  var player = new Player(gameCanvas, keyboard);
  player.Init();

  setInterval(function() {
    gameCanvas.clearRect(0, 0, 1200, 300);
    player.Update();
  }, 20);
}

class Player {
  constructor(canvas, keyboard) {
    this._canvas = canvas;
    this._keyboard = keyboard;
    this._x = 100;
    this._y = 75;
    this._dx = 1;
    this._dy = 1; /// add the underscore
  }

  Init() {
    this.Draw();
  }


  Update() {
    if (this._keyboard.GetIsArrowLeftDown())
      this._x -= this._dx;
    if (this._keyboard.GetIsArrowRightDown())
      this._x += this._dx;
    if (this._keyboard.GetIsArrowUpDown())
      this._y -= this._dy;
    if (this._keyboard.GetIsArrowDownDown())
      this._y += this._dy;

    this.Draw();
  }

  Draw() {
    this._canvas.beginPath();
    this._canvas.arc(this._x, this._y, 50, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    this._canvas.closePath();
    this._canvas.strokeStyle = "black";
    this._canvas.stroke();
    this._canvas.beginPath();
    this._canvas.arc(this._x, this._y, 50, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    this._canvas.closePath();
    this._canvas.fillStyle = "red";
    this._canvas.fill();
  }
}

class Keyboard {
  constructor() {
    this.isArrowLeftDown = false;
    this.isArrowRightDown = false;
    this.isArrowUpDown = false;
    this.isArrowDownDown = false;

    window.addEventListener("keyup", this.OnKeyUpEvent.bind(this)); // use this and bind
    window.addEventListener("keydown", this.OnKeyDownEvent.bind(this));
  }

  OnKeyUpEvent(event) {
    if (event.defaultPrevented) {
      return;
    }

    var key = event.key || event.keyCode;

    if (key == "ArrowLeft")
      this.isArrowLeftDown = false;
    if (key == "ArrowRight")
      this.isArrowRightDown = false;
    if (key == "ArrowUp")
      this.isArrowUpDown = false;
    if (key == "ArrowDown")
      this.isArrowDownDown = false;
  }

  OnKeyDownEvent(event) {
    if (event.defaultPrevented) {
      return;
    }

    var key = event.key || event.keyCode;

    if (key == "ArrowLeft")
      this.isArrowLeftDown = true;
    if (key == "ArrowRight")
      this.isArrowRightDown = true;
    if (key == "ArrowUp")
      this.isArrowUpDown = true;
    if (key == "ArrowDown")
      this.isArrowDownDown = true;
  }

  GetIsArrowLeftDown() {
    return this.isArrowLeftDown;
  }

  GetIsArrowRightDown() {
    return this.isArrowRightDown;
  }

  GetIsArrowUpDown() {
    return this.isArrowUpDown;
  }

  GetIsArrowDownDown() {
    return this.isArrowDownDown;
  }
}
```

```html
<canvas id="gameCanvas"></canvas>
```

NB: You can detect such errors since they are reported in the console.